# Rails controller: update action failing to do SQL UPDATE?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, controller

In a Rails app I have Users who can have notes created under them in each user show view.

From the show view notes can be added and edited. The edit link routes properly to the edit path for each note. Clicking save to update the note redirects back to the user show view.

Here is my notes controller:

```
  def update
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to user_path(@note.user)
  end
```

However, I am trying to update a note entry and in the console I am seeing that it is not updating for some reason. There should be UPDATE step between BEGIN and COMMIT, but it seems to be missing here.

```
Started PUT "/notes/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-01 01:50:25 -0800
Processing by NotesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Wr+urG+6QvsbPuFpVGUEEqc8QVYiu5q8j389YmOi6Zg=", "note"=>{"author"=>"MZ", "note"=>"Test"}, "id"=>"2"}
  Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

What is the reason for why there is no UPDATE step?

Comment: I did not find any udpate active record on the question it self that is `@note.update_attributes(params[:note])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the attributes. You must call `update_attributes` and pass the `params` to be updated.

```
def update
  @note = Note.find(params[:id])             #find the note
  if @note.update_attributes(params[:note])  #update the note
    redirect_to @note.user                   #if attributes updated redirect to @note.user
  else
    render :edit                             #if not, render the form
  end
end
```

Comment: yep... sorry for the misspelling

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You missing the update_attributes. This is the proper way to call the update method. You will get a flash message if the update was successful.

```
def update
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.update_attributes(params[:note]) # you need to make sure about the :note
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@note.user), notice: 'Notes was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render actino: "edit" }
      end
    end
end
```